# Gravar automaticamente numa Pasta predefinida C#

Tags: c#

Alguém me pode indicar o método em C# para gravar um documento numa pasta predefinida em Código? Neste caso queria que o programa grava-se automaticamente no Desktop.

Este é o código que tenho actualmente no button, mas tenciono que faça logo no Load.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      SaveFileDialog salvar = new SaveFileDialog();
        salvar.Filter = "Ficheiro de Configuração|*.cnf";
        salvar.DefaultExt = "txt";
        DialogResult salvou = salvar.ShowDialog();
        if (salvou == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = null;
            try
            {
                sw = new StreamWriter(salvar.FileName);
                sw.WriteLine(txtConfig.Text);
                MessageBox.Show("Gravado com Sucesso!", "Sucesso",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("IOException:\r\n\r\n" + ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception : \r\n\r\n" + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (sw != null)
                    sw.Close();
            }
            this.Close();
        }
 }
```

Cumps

Comment: Que tipo de documento? O que quer dizer com 'automáticamente'?

Comment: @williamhk2 Eu tenho uma textbox com valores escritos.
Eu actualmente tenho um botão que ao clicar, abre o SaveDialog, agora queria que fosse automaticamente no Load, ou seja, ao abrir a Form, o que estiver dentro da textbox vai gravar o ficheiro .txt no Desktop.
Cumps.

Comment: Poderia postar o trecho do código? e descrever isso que você comentou, na pergunta?

Comment: Já está amigo @williamhk2.

Comment: Beleza ;) @GodfatherSantana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na sua função associada ao evento `FormLoad`:

```
private void YourForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    var fileName = Path.Combine(folder, "NomeFixoDoArquivo.cnf");

    File.WriteAllText(fileName, txtConfig.Text);
}
```

`Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop` é um dos jeitos de recuperar a pasta da área de trabalho do usuário logado.

`File.WriteAllText(fileName, txtConfig.Text)` permite que você escreva todo o conteudo do arquivo de uma unica vez.

Comment: Perfeito amigo @JonnyPiazzi! E dá para abrir uma pasta no Desktop e colocar esse ficheiro dentro dela?

Comment: E já agora, depois na outra form, quero que no Load o programa abra o arquivo que gravou, ou seja, o "NomeFixoDoArquivo.cnf".

Comment: a variável `fileName` tem o nome do arquivo. Você pode rodar este mesmo código no outro formulário e abrir o arquivo.

Comment: Além disso a classe `File` tem um método `File.ReadAllText` que lê todo o conteúdo de um arquivo e retorna uma string. Para mais detalhes por favor faça outra pergunta. E não esqueça de marcar como resposta correta se esta te ajudou.

Comment: Amigo @JonnyPiazzi como faço para a outra form ir abrir com um OpenFileDialog o arquivo que gravou? Ela tem que ir buscar o nome do ficheiro automaticamente que foi gravado.