# Obter caminho do desktop

Tags: c#

Boas,
a semana passada expus aqui uma pergunta:

[Gravar automaticamente numa Pasta predefinida C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64167/gravar-automaticamente-numa-pasta-predefinida-c)

Criei agora outro form, e quero que no Load vá buscar automaticamente o ficheiro ao Desktop.
Porém não posso colocar o código abaixo, pois se o programa foi instalado em outras máquinas, o programa vai dar erro.
Como é que coloco o código para ir ao Desktop?

**CÓDIGO**

```
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Users\NOME\Desktop\File.txt");
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Uma pequena observacao: no futuro, evita incluir a linguagem (C#) no titulo da pergunta. É para isso que existem as tags.

Comment: Alterei o titulo para descrever melhor o problema.

Comment: Certo amigo @dcastro! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usa o enum [`Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
string filePath = Path.Combine(desktop, "File.txt");
```

Comment: Amigo @dcastro o Load não está a abrir o documento...

Comment: Faz debug e verifica se o valor de `filePath` esta' correcto.

Comment: Como assim @dcastro?

Comment: @GodfatherSantana Disseste que "o Load não está a abrir o documento".  É impossível diagnosticar o problema só com essa informação. O que é que aconteceu? Qual o código no método Load? Em que parte do código falhou? Foi lançada alguma excepção? Se sim, qual? Quais são os valores das variáveis locais? O caminho do ficheiro está correcto? O ficheiro existe em disco?

Comment: Amigo, basicamente eu faço debug, o form abre mas o programa não abre automaticamente o FILE.txt que se encontra no Ambiente de trabalho...
O código que está no Load, é o que mencionaste em cima, não dá nenhum erro.

Comment: @GodfatherSantana Chamaste o `Process.Start` depois de obter o caminho?

Comment: Não @dcastro, adiciono: " System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"Desktop\FILE.txt");" ?

Comment: @GodfatherSantana Tenta ler e entender o código que eu postei. Fazer só copy paste não é um bom hábito. O código só constrói o caminho para o ficheiro, e guarda o caminho na variável `filePath`.  Depois precisas de abrir o ficheiro, com `Process.Start(filePath)`

Comment: Amigo, consegui resolver, era mesmo um erro no meu código. 
Obrigado!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24026/discussion-between-godfathersantana-and-dcastro).