# Selecionar ficheiro sem usar OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#

Boas, na semana passada coloquei esta questão:

[Obter caminho do desktop](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65376/obter-caminho-do-desktop)

Neste momento queria que o programa no Load, usa-se o método do OpenFileDialog, mas sem que o utilizador tivesse que selecionar o ficheiro que pretende, pois já estaria implementado no código o ficheiro a abrir.
O Código que tenho é este:

**Código**

```
 private void CertificateSigningRequest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        **Abre o ficheiro**
        //string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        //string filePath = Path.Combine(desktop, label1.Text + ".cnf");
        //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);

        **Quero apenas que ele selecione o ficheiro, mas não abra**
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        openFileDialog1.FileName(label1.Text + ".cnf");
    }
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Qual o motivo de utilizar o `OpenFileDialog` se o usuário não vai poder selecionar o ficheiro?

Comment: Era o que eu usava num button. Visto que agora quero no Load, não sei como fazer... @MeuChapeu

Comment: Mas qual o motivo de usar o `OpenFileDialog`? O usuário vai poder escolher outro arquivo, vindo este apenas como padrão ou sempre tem que ser o mesmo arquivo? Porque se é sempre o mesmo e você já sabe o caminho dele não faz sentido usar o `OpenFileDialog`, já que apesar do nome ele não abre nada, ele apenas deixa o usuário escolher um ou mais arquivos.

Comment: E como faço isso @LeandroGodoyRosa? Eu não quero usar mais o OpenFileDialog, quero que o programa apanhe logo o ficheiro.

Comment: No código que você postou as duas primeiras linhas que estão comentadas já pegam o caminho do arquivo, que no caso fica na variável `filePath`, porém só com isso não tenho como saber o que você deve fazer. O que você fazia depois de ter pego o caminho com o OpenFileDialog? Pelo que você disse em outro comentário me parece que ele ficava em uma TextBox, e depois disso, como você usava este valor? Existe alguma função que você precisa chamar passando o caminho? Você pode postar mais algum código de como estava fazendo?

Comment: @LeandroGodoyRosa, o openfiledialog, eu usava para seleccionar o ficheiro que eu me apetecesse. Agora quero que o utilizador não possa escolher, ou seja, selecciona o que eu quero, selecciona sem abrir!

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi, o código carrega um certificado digital usando uma variável de ambiente (no caso, a variável que indica onde é a área de trabalho). O nome do arquivo está em `label1`. Sendo assim, não é necessário usar o `openFileDialog1`:

```
private void CertificateSigningRequest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    string filePath = Path.Combine(desktop, label1.Text + ".cnf");
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);
}
```

Comment: Amigo @CiganoMorrisonMendez, esse código eu já tenho, porém isso está a abrir o ficheiro, eu não quero que ele abra. Só quero que seja seleccionado, sem que o utilizador tenha que usar o OpenFileDialog. Pois quando usava o OpenFileDialog, ficava logo numa textbox o caminho do ficheiro. Eu apenas quero que o ficheiro.cnf esteja selecionado, para que depois o programa corra o código que terei.

Comment: Você quer exibir em uma `textbox` qual certificado a aplicação achou, então?

Comment: Dá para falar consigo sem ser por aqui, para ser mais fácil?

Comment: @GodfatherSantana Tem sim. Me chama no chat.