# Executar comandos do Prompt do Windows e guardar a saída num arquivo de texto

Tags: c#, cmd

Tenho um programa que faz lançar um comando do *Prompt* do Windows.

Eu quero copiar a saída deste comando e guardar num arquivo de texto.

Exemplo: O comando é `ipconfig` e eu quero que a saída seja copiado para um arquivo.

Comment: Veja como [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usa `>` para [redireccionar o output](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29).

```
ipconfig > file.txt
```

Comment: Perfeito @dcastro! "ipconfig > "Ambiente de Trabalho"\ip.txt" assim fica gravado no meu Ambiente de Trabalho, mas se o Windows tiver em Inglês, não ficará gravado. Como poderei colocar para todos?

Comment: @DonVitoCorleone, você pode usar `%userprofile%\Desktop` que será direcionado para a área de trabalho, independente de idioma. Note que `%userprofile%` é uma variável do Windows.

Comment: @DonVitoCorleone Ja fizeste essa mesma pergunta anteriormente: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65376/obter-caminho-do-desktop

Comment: Não amigo @dcastro... Anteriormente era para colocar no código do C#, agora é para escrever na Linha de Comandos...

Comment: Já está a funcionar, consegui arranjar outra forma! Obrigado a todos!

Comment: Amigo @dcastro, isto está a copiar tudo em linha, não é possível fazer os parágrafos?

Answer (score 6):

Você pode fazer isso usando a classe [`Process`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/process):

```
public static string ExecutarCMD(string comando)
{
    using (Process processo = new Process())
    {
        processo.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("comspec");

        // Formata a string para passar como argumento para o cmd.exe
        processo.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/c {0}", comando);

        processo.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processo.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processo.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        processo.Start();
        processo.WaitForExit();

        string saida = processo.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        return saida;
        }
    }
```

**Nota**: Declare os *namespaces* `System.Diagnostics` e `System.IO`.

Use assim:

```
string saida = ExecutarCMD("ipconfig");
File.WriteAllText("NomeArquivo.txt", saida);
```