# pdftocairo: Como salvar o texto da ajuda em arquivo de texto a partir do prompt?

Tags: cmd, prompt, texto

Eu gostaria de salvar o texto de ajuda do programa `pdftocairo` localizado nas subpastas de instalação do `MiKTeX` para Windows.

[image: captura de tela]

O comando `pdftocairo --help > help_pdftocairo.txt`, o qual deveria criar o arquivo `help_pdftocairo.txt` com o conteúdo da ajuda ([como aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67992/executar-comandos-do-prompt-do-windows-e-guardar-a-sa%C3%ADda-num-arquivo-de-texto)), cria, na verdade, um arquivo em branco.

Alguma ideia de como proceder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> É um caso específico onde a saída se dá via **`stderr = 2>`** e não via **`stdout = 1>`**, use **`2>`**

---

O que funcionou aqui com no caso do **`pdftocairo.exe --help`** foi:

```bat
2>pdftocairo.txt pdftocairo --help
```

Visto que esse programa tem a saída direcionada via **`stderr`** e não **`stdout`**, então, ele só vai gravar o conteúdo desejado se tratar como captura de erro(**`stderr`**), e não de uma saída normal(**`stdout`**).